# Drawing line with specified length using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing

How to draw a line with specified length using QGIS 2.16.1?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: This question is just fine.

Answer (score 15):

You need to use `Advanced Digitize tool` which gives you the ability to specify the length and angle also. If the tool is not enabled, then you can enable it from `View -> Panels -> Advanced Digitize tool`.

To activate Advanced Digitize tool, you need to do the following steps:

1. Click on `Start editing` [image]
2. Click on Add Feature tool [image]
3. Click on Advanced Digitize tool [image], which will be enabled at this point

[image]

```
d: Distance
a: Angle
```

The distance relies on the projection's unit (meter, degree, feet) that you are using; hence, you need to be careful about the projection.